# How to import CSS in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to import styles from a css file but I am getting an error saying "control is not defined".
I am using the below format :

```
<div className={`${control} ${emailIsValid === false ? invalid : ''}`}>
```

The below is the codesandox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-architecture-l5gsp?

Comment: Your sandbox does not have related code. Also suggest you to add code here too.

Comment: `control` is a variable not a css class. is the variable defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-architecture-l5gsp?file=/src/App.js

try this, you are using the css class as variable

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add control as a string literal, as its just a classname in your css file and so is invalid -

```
<div className= {`control ${emailIsValid === false ? 'invalid' : ''}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the problem is not with the CSS file but with control,  it is a variable that should be defined in your file.